# Why won't my site load unless it's using www?

Tags: dns

My website will only load into the webpage if I use "www.". I'm using * on the dns source (stands for @ on hostway), so shouldn't it redirect all requests to the webpage? Idk, I'm a beginner, just need some help that's all.

Comment: You should use the term "points to" instead of "redirects" when talking about DNS.   A redirect is an HTTP mechanism for changing the URL of the page the user requested.  That type of change is user visible, as the URL actually changes in the URL bar of the browser.   DNS settings are not typically user visible.   When you create DNS records, they "point" users to your host (or "direct" users to your host), they don't "redirect" them there.  Users will still see your site name in the URL bar, even when you use a `CNAME`. There will be no redirect that changes the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wildcard record you set up matches all subdomains.  It does NOT match the domain apex.   Your website doesn't work for the no-www domain because you do not have a DNS record for it.

To get it to work, you must create an `A` record for the domain apex (`@`) pointing to an IP address given to you by your hosting company.  To do that, leave the `type` field as `A`, put your domain name in the `source` field, (according to the instructions in your screenshot), and enter the IP address in `destination` field.

Note that you are not allowed to create `CNAME` entries for the no-www domain apex.  It is not allowed according to the DNS specifications.   If you try to do so, your website will not work reliably and no email to your domain name will be delivered correctly.

It is possible that your hosting company only supports pointing to them by a hostname.  They may not give you an IP address to use for an A record.  Such hosting companies typically tend to change your site's IP address frequently and without warning.  So if you look up an IP address to use and put it in, your site may stop working before long.

If that is the case, some DNS providers allow `ALIAS` or `ANAME` records.  You create them with the same host name as for a `CNAME`, but they are served as `A` records.   The DNS host periodically (like every few minutes) looks up the IP address for that host, and serves the current value as an `A` record.

It does not appear that hostway supports `ALIAS` records according to https://support.hostway.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000343790-How-do-I-view-and-edit-my-DNS-Records   So if you need an `ALIAS` record, you will have to switch to a different DNS host that supports them.